# Метод вызывающийся перед выгрузкой View из памяти

Tags: xcode, objective-c, ios7

Есть ControllView в который я перехожу Push'ом из другого, как мне выполнить код когда происходит переход обратно?

Answer (score 1):

Ох, больше конкретики надо, когда вопросы задаете.

Если под ControllView, вы понимаете UIViewController, то скорее всего вам помогут методы:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

Эти методы "отрабатывают" при открытии и закрытии ControllView. 
То есть можно при закрытии второго (вызванного) UIControlView выполнить "код" используя метод viewDidDisappear (ниже привожу картинку жизненого цикла)
 [image]

Comment: Я использую viewDidDisappear, но почему-то при переходе обратно с ControllViewB в ControllViewA оно даже не вызывает этот метод.

Comment: Ну это фантастика... Где имнно написан метод? В чем задача?  Совсем круто будет посмотреть код

Comment: Дак кода то и нету, есть ViewControllerA и ViewControllerB, между ниму push связь, в viewDidLoad создание таймера:

    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001 target:self selector:@selector(Tim) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

А при нажатии назад (возвращении к ViewControllerA) нужно отключить таймер.

Comment: Ну так а в чем проблема вызвать метод отключения таймера в момент нажатия "назад"???
За такие вопросы вообще банить надо! Причем все больше подобного - учите матчасть!